# Where are the texts of walking NPCs stored?

Tags: azerothcore

Where are the phrases of walking-npc stored? I've found their waypoints in the `waypoint_data` table, but there is no text for points... And I've found their phrases at `creature_text` and at `broadcast_text`. But I can't find which text for which waypoint. How to find it?

It would also be great to find out the dependence of fields in the tables for adding or correcting localizations, if the text is not inscribed in the Core.

Comment: have you looked into `waypoint_scripts` table? See https://trinitycore.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/tc/pages/2130258/scripts

Answer (score 1):

Texts for waypoints are not stored anywhere because that's not how it works.

When a scripted creature says a text, this means that when that creature reaches a waypoint with a certain ID, It triggers an event that makes him/her/it say a line from `creature_text`.

To make a creature talk when he/she/it reaches a waypoint you will need either a core script or a Smart AI script for that creature. The latest can be found in `smart_scripts`.

If you want to know more about these creature texts you can find Trinity core's documentation about it since our cores are very alike in terms of database structure:

https://trinitycore.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/tc/pages/2130007/creature+text